# Limit notation: what does it mean when no bound is specified?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, notation

In my statistics text it is discussing the limit of a probability of a sequence of events, $ A_1, A_2, ...$, and has this notation:

$$
\lim_i \mathbb{P}(A_i)
$$

Can I just consider this shorthand for this?:

$$
\lim_{i \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_i)
$$

Or is that somehow inappropriate since i is incrementing discretely?

Comment: Yes, it means $i \rightarrow \infty$. I've often seen just $\lim$ used (with no index symbol attached), too.

Comment: $\sum_n$, $\bigcup_n$,$\bigcap_n$ are all short hand for denoting a countable collection of things. More specifically, as $n\to \infty$